# link failure when using > 1 wsdl file in gsoap C client

Tags: java, c++, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using the gSoap facility.

I am attempting to compile C++ code (for dime access) that uses 2 wsdl files. Initially, both functions were in one .wsdl file; however, they have been separated so that a process-intensive service can run on one machine and other functions can run on the old host.

When using one .wsdl file, all is OK and things work (see COMPILE) below. With the commented out portions, all is OK. When adding in the lines (i.e. adding one more additional .wsdl file), I get errors.

When using 2 or more .wsdl files in a client, I get errors (see ERRORS below). I compile using the -n and -p options according to the documentation which results in the error below.

If I do:

```
connect_to_soap_servers/src> grep soap_default_int *.cpp
dukdimeC.cpp:SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_int(struct soap *soap, int *a)
dukdimedcrC.cpp:SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_int(struct soap *soap, int *a)
```

then it shows that (for example) soap_default_int is defined for both: dukdimeC.cpp ~and~ dukdimeC.cpp.

These were generated using the soapcpp2 command that is part of the gSOAP package. I am not using wsdl files to start with as header files are already provided.

Any information that could assist would be greatly appreciated.

TIA, Casey

---

### ERRORS

```
/tmp/cci3r2M7.o: In function `soap_default_byte(soap*, char*)':
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/new:105: multiple definition of `soap_default_byte(soap*, char*)'
/tmp/cc8gONZ4.o:/S190GB/USERS/imgdev//BUSPROJ/code_development/dime/executables/test/connect_to_soap_servers/src/dukdimedcrC.cpp:617: first defined here
/tmp/cci3r2M7.o: In function `soap_default_int(soap*, int*)':
/S190GB/USERS/imgdev//BUSPROJ/code_development/dime/executables/test/connect_to_soap_servers/src/dukdimeC.cpp:1528: multiple definition of `soap_default_int(soap*, int*)'
/tmp/cc8gONZ4.o:/S190GB/USERS/imgdev//BUSPROJ/code_development/dime/executables/test/connect_to_soap_servers/src/dukdimedcrC.cpp:654: first defined here
/tmp/cci3r2M7.o: In function `soap_default_long(soap*, long*)':
/S190GB/USERS/imgdev//BUSPROJ/code_development/dime/executables/test/connect_to_soap_servers/src/dukdimeC.cpp:1592: multiple definition of `soap_default_long(soap*, long*)'
```

---

### Dime_Source (top portion)

```
//gsoap ns service name: condime
//gsoap ns service style: document
//gsoap ns service encoding: literal
//gsoap ns service namespace: urn:dimeServer
//gsoap ns service port: http://localhost:7085
//gsoap ns schema  namespace: urn:condime

typedef char                    *xsd__string;
typedef char                    *xsd__anyURI;
typedef float                   xsd__float;
typedef long                    xsd__int;
typedef double                  xsd__double;
typedef unsigned                long long xsd__positiveInteger;

class ns__Data
{ unsigned char *__ptr; /* points to data */
  int __size;           /* size of data */
  char *id;             /* dime attachment ID (set to NULL to obtain unique cid) */
  char *type;           /* dime attachment content type */
  char *options;        /* dime attachment options (optional) */
  ns__Data();
  struct soap *soap;    /* soap context that created this instance */
};
```

---

### Dime_Source_Decrumple

```
//gsoap ns1 service name: condimedcr
//gsoap ns1 service style: document
//gsoap ns1 service encoding: literal
//gsoap ns1 service namespace: urn:dimedcrServer
//gsoap ns1 service port: http://localhost:7086
//gsoap ns1 schema  namespace: urn:condimedcr


typedef char                    *xsd__string;
typedef char                    *xsd__anyURI;
typedef float                   xsd__float;
typedef long                    xsd__int;
typedef double                  xsd__double;
typedef unsigned                long long xsd__positiveInteger;
```

---

### MAKEFILE portion

```
CLNT_DECR_SRCS = dukdimedcrcondimedcrProxy.cpp dukdimedcrC.cpp dukdimedcrClient.cpp
#CLNT_DIME_SRCS = dukdimecondimeProxy.cpp dukdimeC.cpp dukdimeClient.cpp

all: client

client: Dime_Source_Decrumple DimeFunc_dll.cpp $(SOAPH) $(SOAPCPP)
        $(GSOAP) -x -n -pdukdimedcr Dime_Source_Decrumple
        $(GSOAP) -x -i -pdukdimedcr Dime_Source_Decrumple
#       $(GSOAP) -x -n -pdukdime Dime_Source
#       $(GSOAP) -x -i -pdukdime Dime_Source
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) DimeFunc_dll.cpp -o $(CLNT_OUT)  $(CLNT_DECR_SRCS)       $(CLNT_DIME_SRCS) $(SOAPCPP) $(LIBS)`
```